# CosmosDB source returning DF-SYS-01

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've built some pipelines and had success importing data from most of my CosmosDB tables, but this one constantly gives me an error which I don't understand. I think it might be caused by table structure, but would highly appreciate second opinion and possible solutions.

Table item:

```
{
"id": "someGuid",
"name": "someString",    
"pins": [
    {
        "type": "someString",
        "latitude": 47.03923,
        "longitude": -122.89136,
        "name": "someString"
    },
    {
        "type": "someString",
        "latitude": 28.53823,
        "longitude": -81.37739,
        "name": "someString"
    }
],
"_rid": "vj04AOrfr2s8CT0AAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/vj04AA==/colls/vj04AOrfr2s=/docs/vj04AOrfr2s8CT0AAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"ac00ddc8-0000-0700-0000-5e7428230000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1584670755
}
```

Columns are identified correct in Source.Projection Tab where pins are []string, but source can't be loaded ((

```
"{"message":"at : (StructType(StructField(area,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true), StructField(resultType,StringType,true), StructField(results,ArrayType(StringType,true),true), StructField(test,StringType,true)),StringType) (of class scala.Tuple2). Details:at : (StructType(StructField(area,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true), StructField(resultType,StringType,true), StructField(results,ArrayType(StringType,true),true), StructField(test,StringType,true)),StringType) (of class scala.Tuple2)","failureType":"UserError","target":"Pins","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by : 1. restarting ADF session  2. Resetting schema for data source - it automatically picked correct schema. Hopefully this answer will help someone in the feature.